# How to get list column which is in xslt list view webpart in in JQuery?

Tags: xslt, sharepoint

I am customizing NewForm.aspx in SP2013 in Designer 2013. I am struggling to get  column values from XSLT list view web part in SharePoint designer 2013. I need to manipulate with columns in JQuery to do some action (like hiding, disabling etc.). Currently, I am getting column ID via Developer tool hovering over it but this is not proper way since ID will change in Quality/Production.
Example:-

```
$("#ctl00_ctl33_g_1ea47d6f_1fed_4426_8e49_cda9970429d6_ff21_ctl00_ctl00_TextField").val("Close");
```

I want something like:-

```
$("#column2").val("Close");
```

My XSLT in SP Designer 2013 looks like:-

```
<tr><td>
<H3>column2</H3>
</td>
<td>
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff3{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit"     
FieldName="column2" __designer:bind="  
{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff3',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@column2')}"/>
<SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff3description{$Pos}" FieldName="column2" ControlMode="Edit"/>
</td>
</tr>
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

It's standard ASP.NET behavior that ID of server control is not ID of HTML element that is representing the control. And many of SharePoint controls are rendered by many DIVs and SPANs (especially columns like people, formatted text, ...). So reading and setting values of them is quite complicated process.

Generally you can use title attribute to search for HTML tag that contains HTML element of particular field. Title attribute contains name of the field. For required fields it contains also required information. Or you can try to search for elements with ID starting with internal name of the field. But in both cases you will need to add some additional logic to find the right control containing the value of the field. The logic will need to reflect the type of field you are looking for.

The easiest way is to use some libraries like [SPJSutility](http://spjsblog.com/2010/05/28/get-or-set-value-for-sharepoint-field-in-newform-editform-and-dispform-get-only-in-dispform/) or [form designer](http://spform.com/documentation/js/manager) to manipulate with form fields.

You can not disable even the simplest textboxes by setting enabled attribute to false because in that case the value will not be processed on the server.

Comment: Hi Jan, Thanks for your post. It was helpful. Actually, I was seeking for fields ID attribute, so I can use it in JQuery for hidding/enabling etc. However, XSLT doesn't give me ID. My fetch IDs from developer tool but it will change when I move to another environment. Can you help me out in this?